# how to transfer a character to a variable in r

Tags: r, variables, character

Does anybody know how to transfer a character to a variable? What I want to do is:

```
loc1 = data.frame(year=c(1993, 1994, 1995), percentage=c(0.2, 0.3, 0.5))

data = data.frame(x=c(2,3,4), y=c('a','b','c'), location=c('loc1','loc2','loc3'))

data[1, 3]

loc1 Levels: loc1 loc2 loc3
```

How can I achieve that return value loc1 is not a factor but the data frame that I previously defined?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: `help("get")`, but there might be a better strategy for whatever your actual objective is.

Comment: have a look at `get(as.character(data[1, 3]))`

Comment: That's super helpful! Thanks a million!